# Jupyter Notebook with Apache Spark (Kernel Error)

Tags: python, apache-spark, ipython, pyspark, apache-toree

My objectif is to use Jupyter Notebook (IPython) with Apache Spark. I'm using Apache Toree to do this. I was setting environment variable for SPARK_HOME and configuring Apache Toree installation with Jupyter. Everything seems fine.

When I run the below command, a juypter browser is opened **ipython notebook --profile=pyspark**

[image]

When I choose **Apache Toree - PySpark** in the drop-down menu, I can't code in my notebook and I have this view (Python 2 is OK):

[image]

The red button gives :

[image]

What's wrong ? Help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer, but if you're not hooked on toree and just need a local spark for learning and experimenting, you could download a copy of spark, unzip it and use this in the beginning of your notebook:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="<path where you have extracted the spark file>"
sys.path.append( os.path.join(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'], 'python') )
sys.path.append( os.path.join(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'], 'bin') )
sys.path.append( os.path.join(os.environ['SPARK_HOME'], 'python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip') )

from pyspark import SparkContext,SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
import pyspark.sql.functions as sql


sc = SparkContext()
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
print sc.version
```